# How can I call a variable from an array that has a type of struct?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

How can I call the image variable that is inside the array?

```
static let data: [Meditation] = [
        Meditation(title: "1 Minute Relaxing Meditation", description: "Clear your mind and slumber into nothingness. Allocate only a few moments for a quick breather.", duration: 70, track: "meditation1", image: "Ambient"),
        Meditation(title: "1 Minute Relaxing Meditation", description: "Clear your mind and slumber into nothingness. Allocate only a few moments for a quick breather.", duration: 70, track: "meditation1", image: "World"),
        Meditation(title: "1 Minute Relaxing Meditation", description: "Clear your mind and slumber into nothingness. Allocate only a few moments for a quick breather.", duration: 70, track: "meditation1", image: "Pop"),
        Meditation(title: "1 Minute Relaxing Meditation", description: "Clear your mind and slumber into nothingness. Allocate only a few moments for a quick breather.", duration: 70, track: "meditation1", image: "HipHop"),
        Meditation(title: "1 Minute Relaxing Meditation", description: "Clear your mind and slumber into nothingness. Allocate only a few moments for a quick breather.", duration: 70, track: "meditation1", image: "R&B"),
        Meditation(title: "1 Minute Relaxing Meditation", description: "Clear your mind and slumber into nothingness. Allocate only a few moments for a quick breather.", duration: 70, track: "meditation1", image: "EDM")
    ]
```

I have tried; however, it does not work.

```
meditation.data.image
```

Comment: `data` is an array, so you have to provide an index. For example, `data[0].image` or `data.first?.image`

Answer (score 1):

Since data is an `array`, you can’t just call `.image`. You have to know which element’s image you want then access it.

If you want the first element, simply call:

```
meditation.data.first?.image
```

If not, you need to `filter` the array or use an index in order to get the element you want:

```
meditation.data[3].image//fourth image
```

Answer (score 1):

**As data variable is an array of Meditation types.**

For accessing the value in an array we need to use the index value as given below:

**For the 0th index**, we can access image as **meditation.data[0].image** // Ambient

**For the 1st index**, we can access image as **meditation.data[1].image** // World

**For the 2nd index**, we can access image as **meditation.data[2].image** // Pop

**For the 3rd index**, we can access image as **meditation.data[3].image** // HipHop

**For the 4th index**, we can access image as **meditation.data[4].image** // R&B

**For the 5th index**, we can access image as **meditation.data[5].image** // EDM